# Greedy algorithm to divide objects into the lowest number of groups of a maximum size

Tags: algorithms, greedy-algorithms

I have n objects of independent size s, and need to group them so that the sum of the sizes of each group is smaller than a given maximum size, and the number of groups is the smallest possible.

I already tried a brute force algorithm that orders the objects in all possible permutations and then, based on their size and the group max size, divides every permutation in groups based on the order. This algorithm is very slow and therefore I want to find a greedy one, but being new to the topic I can't think of a good way to start.

My idea would be to start building the first group from the largest object, and then adding more so that every time I add a new one, the difference between the max size and the size of all the objects in the group is minimized. Is this a good starting point?

Comment: Is the size of every object $s$? That is, do all the objects have the same size? If the answer is "yes" then the problem is very easy to solve: the number of needed groups is $\left\lceil \frac{n}{\lfloor G/s \rfloor} \right\rceil$, where $G$ is the group size. If the answer is "no" then keep in mind that you are dealing with a NP-hard problem. See [Bin Packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) for heuristics and approximation algorithms.

Comment: @Steven the sizes are independent from each other. I do not understand which type of bin packing problem this is, as I am very new to this subject. Could you please explain more in detail?

Comment: @Steven how about an approach in which I start filling the first group by fetching the object with the largest weight and then I fill the difference with the largest object that can fit in it, and so on?

Comment: Your problem is *exactly* bin packing. See the definition on the wikipedia page that I linked to you. The algorithm you describe is First Fit Decreasing (FFD) on the wikipedia page. If $k$ is the optimal number of groups then FFD returns a solution that uses at most $\frac{11k + 6}{9} < 2k$ groups.